# How do I modify default form values generated by Razor View Engine in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**Razor** view engine generated default values when a property is **non-nullable**. So how do I **override** these default value?

**This is the form:**

[image]

**and this is the Model:**

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Created on")]
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(1,20)]
    [Display(Name = "Number in Stock")]
    public int NumberInStock { get; set; }

    public Genre Genre { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Genre")]
    public int GenreId { get; set; }

}
```

**a snippet of one property from the view looks like this:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Movie.DateAdded)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Movie.DateAdded, "{0:d MMM yyyy}", new { 
    @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Movie.DateAdded)
</div>
```

Comment: when you provide a model into the view, assign the values you need.

Comment: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Movie.NumberInStock , new { @Value =111}) `

Comment: Where do I assign them? In model itself? @trailmax

Comment: The funny thing I was trying many times in the past days is `@value` with lowercase "v" which does not work. Now I came back I kept trying and I discovered it works only with uppercase "Value" or "`@Value`". @hasta tamang

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine with your model always being populated with a specific default value (so, not only in this view but wherever you create a new instance of your model), then `DefaultValueAttribute` is probably the best solution.

e.g.

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Release Date")]
[DefaultValue(typeof(DateTime), "2019-01-01 00:00:00")]
public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
```

More info on `DefaultValueAttribute` in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute?view=netcore-2.2).